# Mention private chatter groups

Tags: chatter, public-group, chatter-groups, collaborationgroup

Can users @mention private chatter groups, that they are not a member of? The idea is to restrict members of a group (which is why I prefer private group), but non-member users be able to @mention the group.

And can I use @mention on email addresses? Can I use @mention on a public group?

**Edit 1:** This is for a support team containing 20+ users. Currently we're mentioning all users, but some get missed at times. The team works in shifts, so mentioning only a few doesn't seem to work, hence thinking of Chatter Groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only members of a private group can @mention it.

Any user can @mention a public group. 
[At Mention Help Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_add_mentioning_people.htm&type=0)

Using the Connect API (REST API) you can @mention a username (effectively their email address). [Message Segment Input: Mention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_requests_msg_seg_input_mention.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Can I restrict membership in a public group?

Comment: No, you cannot restrict membership in a public group.